# I want to use output of find command to unzip cmd

Tags: shell-script, find, zip

I need to use output of

```
find / -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1,1nr | head -1
```

command to a unzip command in shell script. Please help

Comment: Welcome to U&L, as is your question is hard to answer. 
You'll need to store output in a variable use : `var=$( command )` then unzip using   `unzip foo.zip $var` However, as is $var will hold filename and timestamp.

Comment: Maybe `xargs` is your friend. Please make clear what should happen.

Comment: You want to call `unzip` on the most recently modified file in the whole system.  You know this is most likely a log file or your own shell's history file, or some other non-zip file?

Comment: Thank you @Archemar it works for me

Comment: @user383138 Sorry? What works? If you have a solution that works, please consider writing a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

To unzip the most recently modified file (with a `.zip` filename suffix) from somewhere under a directory `$dir` *using the `zsh` shell*:

```
unzip $dir/**/*.zip(.Dom[1])
```

The glob qualifier `(.Dom[1])` at the end modifies the behaviour of the preceding pattern to only match regular files (`.`), i.e. not directories etc, and to also match hidden names (`D`, works like the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`).  The `om` orders the results in order of decreasing modification time, and `[1]` picks out only the first result.  Use a upper-case `O` in place of lower-case `o` to sort the other way around.

The `**` pattern works just like in `bash` when the `globstar` shell option is set, which means it matches "recursively" down into subdirectories.

From `bash`, this could be done with

```
zsh -c 'unzip $1/**/*.zip(.Dom[1])' zsh "$dir"
```

for some directory `$dir`.

Comment: Note that zsh had `**` 17 years before `bash`. I thought it was a zsh invention, but the documentation of `unzip`'s (optional) `-W` option suggests it may be coming from Acorn RISC OS.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! I'm making comparisons with `bash` as that may be the more known shell amongst current Linux users.

Comment: Wow so many options in zsh !! I only used it in macOS (was it zsh ?), I might use it in linux as well.

Comment: @Archemar Since macOS Catalina, `zsh` is the default shell for new user accounts, but the shell has been in the base system for a long time.